# Configuring coc.nvim coc-solargraph with standardrb for RSpec files

Tags: vimrc, plugin-coc, filetype-ruby, lsp

I am trying to configure coc.nvim for my vim 8.2. I mapped my formatting to leader-d with:

```
nnoremap <Leader>d :call CocAction('format') <CR>
```

which works fine for ruby filetype. However, when I load `_spec.rb` files, with `ruby.rspec` filetype, my diagnostics are not being shown and my format mapping returns:

```
Error on request (format): Format provider not found for buffer: ...
```

My `coc-config.json`:

```
{
  "codeLens.enable": true,
  "solargraph.useBundler": false,
  "solargraph.commandPath": "/Users/dontmatter/.rbenv/shims/solargraph",
  "solargraph.formatting": true,
  "solargraph.diagnostics": true,
  "solargraph.checkGemVersion": true
}
```

and I am using `standardrb` config for rubocop:

```
  - standard
  - rubocop-rspec

inherit_gem:
  # First check this: https://github.com/testdouble/standard#how-do-i-run-standard-in-my-editor
  # If your editor invokes 'rubocop' directly and knows nothing about 'standard' gem, 
  # it can be useful to inherit 'standard' set of rules
  standard: config/base.yml
  
# You can also override standardrb rules
Style/StringLiterals:
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes

# Or enable additional Cops
RSpec:
  Enabled: true
```

Is there a way to enable solargraph to run on ruby.rspec filetype?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to reach out to the coc.nvim maintainers/community as well. If you get an answer, be sure to post it in the answer section below!

Answer (score 1):

The setting I was looking for is called `coc_fileype_map`([doc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/blob/master/doc/coc.txt#L1525)). To make solargraph lint and autofix `rspec.ruby` file types, the following setting had to be added to my vimrc:

```
let g:coc_filetype_map = {
  \ 'rspec.ruby': 'ruby',
  \ }
```

Unfortunately, I didn't help me because Solargraph would crash trying to parse RSpec DSL as Ruby. I ended up uninstalling rspec-vim and letting vim treat *_spec.rb files as "normal" ruby files.